# How to create a VIEW when Table1 is having relation to Table2 on several of it's fields?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, join, query, view

My situation (greatly simplified) is as follows:

#### Table1

- ID
- Name
- Ver1
- Ver2
- Ver3
- Ver4

#### Table2

- ID
- Name
- ...

This table holds the versions

The columns `Ver1` - `Ver4` are foreign keys and are `ID`s of `Table2` rows.

I want to create a `viewTable1` that will show the `Name` from `Table1` and then the names of all the versions from `Table2`.

A terrible way I can think of is simply wrapping `SELECT` queries one on top of the other, each time getting the `Name` of a single version via a single `JOIN`. But there must be a smarter way.

What's the easiest way to do that?

### Example of data and required View output:

#### Table1

```
 ID  | Name | Ver1 | Ver2 | Ver3 | Ver4 
-----+------+------+------+------+------
 01  | AAAA |  05  |  01  |  04  |  03
```

#### Table2

```
ID | Name     | ...
---+----------+------ 
01 | NameOfV1 | ...
02 | NameOfV2 | 
03 | NameOfV3 | 
04 | NameOfV4 | 
05 | NameOfV5 |
```

#### SQL Statement to query view

```
SELECT From ViewTable1 WHERE ID=1"
```

The above query should return this record set:

```
01 AAAA NameOfV5 NameOfV1 NameOfV4 NameOfV3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would normalize your data. If you can not do that, then there are at least two ways to accomplish this.

**[DB FIDDLE For Both Examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d330a000eb22aa42b45ca297b140c7c)**

You can view the execution plans of these simplified queries [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1HiznWrS).

**UNPIVOT > JOIN > PIVOT Method**

One way is to `UNPIVOT` your `Table1`, then `JOIN` to `Table2`, and then `PIVOT` back to a single row.

```
declare @Table1 table(ID int, [Name] varchar(16), Ver1 int, Ver2 int, Ver3 int, Ver4 int)

declare @Table2 table (ID int, [Name] varchar(16))

insert into @Table1
values
(1,'AAAA',5,1,4,3)

insert into @Table2
values
(1,'NameOfV1'),
(2,'NameOfV2'),
(3,'NameOfV3'),
(4,'NameOfV4'),
(5,'NameOfV5')


select
    ID
    ,BaseName
    ,[1] as Ver1
    ,[2] as Ver2
    ,[3] as Ver3
    ,[4] as Ver4
from
(
    select
        u.ID
        ,u.[Name] BaseName
        ,t2.[Name] VersionName
        ,RN = row_number() over ( partition by u.ID order by (select null))
    from 
        (
        select ID, [Name], Ver1, Ver2, Ver3, Ver4
        from @Table1 t1
        ) s
    unpivot
        (
        FKID for FKIDs in (Ver1, Ver2, Ver3, Ver4)
        ) u
    inner join
        @Table2 t2 on t2.ID = FKID
    ) s
pivot
    (
    max(VersionName) for RN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) p
```

**Multi-Self-JOIN Aggregation Method**

Similarly, you could just `JOIN` 4 times, and use an aggregate function.

```
select
    t.ID
    ,t.[Name]
    ,Ver1 = max(t1.Name)
    ,Ver2 = max(t2.Name)
    ,Ver3 = max(t3.Name)
    ,Ver4 = max(t4.Name)
from @Table1 t
inner join
    @Table2 t1 on t1.ID = t.Ver1
inner join
    @Table2 t2 on t2.ID = t.Ver2
inner join
    @Table2 t3 on t3.ID = t.Ver3
inner join
    @Table2 t4 on t4.ID = t.Ver4
group by
    t.ID
    ,t.[Name]
```